# Getting properties of each feature in feature collection using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I would simply like to get the properties of each feature in a feature collection. For example, in the screenshot, I would like to return the value of "1" from "site."

Here is my code:

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/adrianom/sites_aea");
var SearchArea = table;
var size_fc = SearchArea.size().getInfo();
var fc_list = SearchArea.toList(size_fc);
var first_fc = ee.Feature(fc_list.get(0));
var fc_properties = first_fc.propertyNames();
```

This will get the property names of a single feature, but I want to loop through every property. Additionally, I would like to know if there is a better way of getting to a single feature's properties in a feature collection.

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of the attribute keys and map the dictionary onto a new attribute which can then be printed out.

```
var features = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level0")
var keys = features.first().toDictionary().keys()
var attributes = features.map(function (f) {
  return features.set('dict', f.toDictionary(keys));
});
print(attributes.aggregate_array('dict'))
```